# Program type already present: io.invertase.firebase.BuildConfig

Tags: react-native

Based on some googling, it seems that there is some overlap between 2 packages.  I've encountered a similar issue in the past and I think I was able to fix it with ./gradlew clean, but that isn't fixing my current issue.  Here's the error:

Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
>     Program type already present: io.invertase.firebase.BuildConfig

I started encountering this issue as I was trying to get react-native-firebase wired up into my application.  Here are a few relevant dependencies in my package.json file:

```
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^6.0.3",
"@react-native-firebase/database": "^6.0.3",
"firebase-auth": "^0.1.2",
"react-native-firebase": "^5.5.6",
```

Do I need to uninstall one of these packages or is it possible that I made a wireup mistake in a file like build.gradle, MainApplication.java?

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I have exactly the same error than you have?

Answer (score 17):

Once manually removing the ./node_modules/react-native-firebase folder,
I was able to successfully run: npx react-native run-android

I was able to successfully  react-native run-android

Comment: Thanks, Its working. Make sure you remove `react-native-firebase` not `@react-native-firebase` and also remove this two lines 1.  `import io.invertase.firebase.auth.RNFirebaseAuthPackage;`, 2.`packages.add(new RNFirebaseAuthPackage());` from `MainApplication.java` if you added for manually installation.

Comment: you really saved my day

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to look for you react native error at yarn android / react-native run-android

```
error React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies, but the following modules are linked manually:
  - @react-native-community/async-storage (to unlink run: "react-native unlink @react-native-community/async-storage")
  - @react-native-community/google-signin (to unlink run: "react-native unlink @react-native-community/google-signin")
  - @react-native-community/viewpager (to unlink run: "react-native unlink @react-native-community/viewpager")
  - react-native-blur-overlay (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-blur-overlay")
  - react-native-date-picker (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-date-picker")
  - react-native-extra-dimensions-android (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-extra-dimensions-android")
  - react-native-fs (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-fs")
  - react-native-gesture-handler (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-gesture-handler")
  - react-native-linear-gradient (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-linear-gradient")
  - react-native-push-notification (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-push-notification")
  - react-native-svg (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-svg")
  - react-native-vector-icons (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-vector-icons")
  - rn-fetch-blob (to unlink run: "react-native unlink rn-fetch-blob")
```

Just do the `react-native unlink <specified-package>` for all, it works for me cleared all the errors

but make sure some of them would break your functionality or ui

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me. I removed these lines.

**settings.gradle**

`include ':@react-native-firebase_crashlytics' project(':@react-native-firebase_crashlytics').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, './../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/crashlytics/android')`

**android/app/build.gradle**

`implementation project(path: ":@react-native-firebase_crashlytics")`