# R8: Program type already present: io.invertase.firebase.BuildConfig in react in React Native app

Tags: react-native, proguard, android-r8

i have created a react native app and then try to create a release apk file by follow the link: https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android

But it's showing an error which is:

```
> Task :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForRelease FAILED
R8: Program type already present: io.invertase.firebase.BuildConfig

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

``
so what should i do to resolve this issue,please help me
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58646207/program-type-already-present-io-invertase-firebase-buildconfig) answer your question?

Comment: @Rohit Actually, i am using the firebase for push notification and crashylics so, how can i remove this firebase node_module